# On select when using prevAll() dont update values correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select fields where you chose time, from and to. I want to prevent users from picking a 'to' time before 'from'.

The problem is if you pick 'from' `08:30`, the first time it works correctly, you can't select on select 'to' lower than this. However if you change the first selection from again to `07:00` the select to is not updating and you are stuck. You can pick only from first selection.

```js
$("#from").change(function() {
  var fromVal = $(this).val();
  var min_time_limit = parseInt(fromVal) + 4;
  $('#to').val(min_time_limit);
  $('#to option[value="' + min_time_limit + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart">
  <select id="from" name="from" class="from">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>
  <select id="to" name="to" class="to">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Please check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzdo324j/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you never re-enable the `option` elements when you move to an earlier `#from` time. You need to re-arrange your logic to first re-enable the `#to` options, then filter the ones earlier than `#from` and disable them. Try this:

```js
$("#from").change(function() {
  var fromVal = $(this).val();
  var min_time_limit = parseInt(fromVal) + 4;

  var $to = $('#to').val(min_time_limit);
  var $options = $to.children('option').prop('disabled', false);
  $options.filter('[value="' + min_time_limit + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart">
  <select id="from" name="from" class="from">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>

  <select id="to" name="to" class="to">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Also note that a another way to do this would be to relate the options in both selects by index, as the values are the same:

```js
$("#from").change(function() {
  var toIndex = $(this).children('option:selected').index() + 4;
  var $availableOptions = $('#to option').prop('disabled', false);
  var $selectedOption = $availableOptions.eq(toIndex).prop('selected', true);
  $selectedOption.prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart">
  <select id="from" name="from" class="from">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>

  <select id="to" name="to" class="to">
    <option value="1">07:00</option>
    <option value="2">07:30</option>
    <option value="3">08:00</option>
    <option value="4">08:30</option>
    <option value="5">09:00</option>
    <option value="6">09:30</option>
    <option value="7">10:00</option>
    <option value="8">10:30</option>
    <option value="9">11:00</option>
    <option value="10">11:30</option>
    <option value="11">12:00</option>
    <option value="12">12:30</option>
    <option value="13">13:00</option>
    <option value="14">13:30</option>
    <option value="15">14:00</option>
    <option value="16">14:30</option>
    <option value="17">15:00</option>
    <option value="18">15:30</option>
    <option value="19">16:00</option>
    <option value="20">16:30</option>
    <option value="21">17:00</option>
    <option value="22">17:30</option>
    <option value="23">18:00</option>
    <option value="24">18:30</option>
    <option value="25">19:00</option>
    <option value="26">19:30</option>
    <option value="27">20:00</option>
    <option value="28">20:30</option>
    <option value="29">21:00</option>
    <option value="30">21:30</option>
    <option value="31">22:00</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You need to use `$('#to option').prop('disabled', false);` just before you disable the options for the `to` select.
2. You need to do `var min_time_limit = parseInt(fromVal) + 1;` so that it disables exactly the required number of options in the `to` select.

```js
$("#from").change(function() {
  var fromVal = $(this).val();
  var min_time_limit = parseInt(fromVal) + 1;
  $('#to').val(min_time_limit);
  // enable all the options
  $('#to option').prop('disabled', false);
  // disable only the required options
  $('#to option[value="' + min_time_limit + '"]').prevAll().prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="from" name="from" class="from">
  <option value="1">07:00</option>
  <option value="2">07:30</option>
  <option value="3">08:00</option>
  <option value="4">08:30</option>
  <option value="5">09:00</option>
</select>

<select id="to" name="to" class="to">
  <option value="1">07:00</option>
  <option value="2">07:30</option>
  <option value="3">08:00</option>
  <option value="4">08:30</option>
  <option value="5">09:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make all not disabled

```
$('#to option').prop('disabled', false);
```

before to mark as disabled

https://jsfiddle.net/kxg5qczf/